# Copying text out of PDF includes greek characters

Tags: pdf, characters

I'm having an issue where if I copy words out of a PDF (generated with XeLaTeX) where the text copied out includes random Greek characters.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english]{report}
% setup encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%set language
\usepackage[british,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,cmap}
%setup font
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}

\begin{document}
{\large A dissertation submitted in partial fulfilment of\\
the requirements for the degree of\\}
\end{document}
```

(I've omitted text for simplicity).

Generating a PDF for the above and copying out the body, gives the following string:

```
A dissertaƟon submiƩed in parƟal fulĮlment of the requirements for the degree of
```

If I remove the font inclusion, then copy paste works fine, so I've reason to believe it's an issue with how I'm using the font? Anyone got any ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `inputenc`, `lmodern`, `cmap` and `fontenc` with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. But beside this it is a problem with the ligatures. They are not correctly mapped to unicode entries with XeLaTeX. With LuaLaTeX it works:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english]{report}
\usepackage[british,english]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri.ttf}

\begin{document}
{\large A dissertation submitted in partial fulfilment of\\
the requirements for the degree of\par}
\end{document}
```

#### XeLaTeX:

A dissertaon submied in paral fulfilment of
the requirements for the degree of

#### LuaLaTeX

A dissertation submitted in partial fulfilment of
the requirements for the degree of

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you, removing those packages and changing over to LuaLaTeX as per your recommendation resolved my issue!